# Trying to load and save login cookies in linkedin using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, linkedin-api, pickle

```
class Browser:
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        chrome_options = Options()
        prefs = {
            "download_restrictions": 3,
        }
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
            "prefs", prefs
        )
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
        self.driver=driver          
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
        self.login()
        
    def login(self):
        try:
            print("trying to load cookie if available")
            self.loadcookie()
            return
        except:
            print("some problem with cookie or its not available")
            traceback.print_exc()
            
        self.driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(self.username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(self.password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys("\n")
        try:
            self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Skip']").click()
        except:
            pass
        self.savecookies()
    def loadcookie(self):
        print("loading cookie")
        cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
        for cookie in cookies:
                self.driver.add_cookie(cookie)
            
    def savecookies(self):
        print("saving cookie")
        time.sleep(10)
        pickle.dump( self.driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

the  above given is my code to create a browser instance , then login into linkedin
and save cookies  **if not avaiable** ,
the problem here i am facing is ,the browser has no issue in saving the cookie, but it has issues loading the saved cookie , here is what my console looks like,

```
trying to load cookie if available
loading cookie
some problem with cookie or its not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bot\Desktop\ongoing\linkedpy\Browser.py", line 46, in login
    self.loadcookie()
  File "C:\Users\bot\Desktop\ongoing\linkedpy\Browser.py", line 65, in loadcookie
    self.driver.add_cookie(cookie)
  File "C:\Users\bot\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 894, in add_cookie
    self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})
  File "C:\Users\bot\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\bot\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: invalid cookie domain
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)

saving cookie
```

here are my cookies, i have hid the value key on purpose,

```
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1633529354, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'AnalyticsSyncHistory', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1638713354, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'li_sugr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1638713353, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_guid', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1694051195, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'bcookie', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.www.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1632146950, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'timezone', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1633529352, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'aam_uuid', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'AMCVS_14215E3D5995C57C0A495C55%40AdobeOrg', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1638713348, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'liap', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1633529354, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'lms_ads', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.www.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1638713348, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'JSESSIONID', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1638713348, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_gcl_au', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1633529354, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'UserMatchHistory', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1646489352, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'AMCV_14215E3D5995C57C0A495C55%40AdobeOrg', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.www.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1662473348, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'li_at', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'lang', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.www.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1694051195, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'bscookie', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1633529354, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'lms_analytics', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.www.linkedin.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'spectroscopyId', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1631023233, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'lidc', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
{'domain': '.www.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1662473348, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'li_rm', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': ''}
```

I also tried doing this because i thought there might be some problem with a few key pairs,

```
def loadcookie(self):
        print("loading cookie")
        cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
        for cookie in cookies:
            try:
                self.driver.add_cookie(cookie)
            except:
                pass
```

but I had no luck with this too, I dont get whats wrong here because I am sure cookie.pkl file is ok and being created perfectly,
please help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on a pre-existing github repo although, I still don't get the reason for the problem, so people are still welcome to answer

here is the solution,

```
    def loadcookie(self):
        print("loading cookie")
        cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
        print(cookies)
        self.driver.add_cookie(cookies)
        print('loaded cookie')
    def savecookies(self):
        print("saving cookie")
        time.sleep(10)
        cookies=self.driver.get_cookies()
        for cookie in cookies:
            if(cookie['name']=='li_at'):
                cookie['domain']='.linkedin.com'
                x={
                'name': 'li_at',
                'value': cookie['value'],
                'domain': '.linkedin.com'
                }
                break
        pickle.dump(x , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
        print('cookies saved')
```

I had to load linkedin.com before loading cookies into the browser